# SQL - Select most 'active' timespan fromdb

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a table of transactions.  In this table I store the transaction datetime in UTC.  I have a few months of data, about 20,000 transactions a day.

How would I write a stored procedure to:

A:  Count of the most active/busiest hour

B:  Return which hour was the most active/busiest

Comment: What have you tried so far? A friendly suggestion - you will typically get better results on SO if you try something and then come here with what you are stuck on.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know where to start.  I imagine some sort of group by.  I have only started working with SQL in the last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select datepart(hour, the_column) as [hour], count(*) as total
from t
group by datepart(hour, the_column)
order by total desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I was unaware of datepart.