# SQL - select most 'active' time from db

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

Very closely related to [SQL - Select most 'active' timespan fromdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938302/sql-select-most-active-timespan-fromdb) but different question.

"I have a table of transactions. In this table I store the transaction datetime in UTC. I have a few months of data, about 20,000 transactions a day."

How would change

```
  select datepart(hour, the_column) as [hour], count(*) as total 
  from t 
  group by datepart(hour, the_column) 
  order by total desc
```

so that I can select the specific year, month, day, hour, minute, and second that was the most 'active'.

To clarify, I'm not looking for which hour or minute of the day was most active.  Rather, which moment in time was the most active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
    DATEPART(year, the_column) as year
    ,DATEPART(dayofyear,the_column) as day
    ,DATEPART(hh, the_column) as hour
    ,DATEPART(mi,the_column) as minute
    ,DATEPART(ss, the_column) as second
    ,count(*) as count from t
Group By 
    DATEPART(year, the_column)
    , DATEPART(dayofyear,the_column)    
    , DATEPART(hh, the_column)
    , DATEPART(mi,the_column)
    , DATEPART(ss, the_column)
order by count desc
```

Answer (score 2):

If minute resolution is enough:

```
select top 1 cast(the_column as smalldatetime) as moment, count(*) as total 
from t 
group by cast(the_column as smalldatetime)
order by total desc
```

Comment: Minute is enough resolution, unfortunately, this method was rounding up datetimes with the cast.  For example, 2012-08-21 23:19:59:957 would be cast as 2012-08-21 23:20, therefore skewing my results.